# Logging changes to environment variables

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, login, display-manager

I'm trying to debug some login behaviour where I have both my display manager and systemd (and potentially others) altering some environment variables (the `XDG_*` variables). Does anyone know any way of logging which processes have set or unset an environment variable? My best guess so far is some `LD_PRELOAD` trick on `setenv`, `unsetenv` and `putenv`, but *surely* there's got to be a more obvious way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: or `strace` the relevant processes, or maybe `sysdig` or such can log the calls

Comment: `strace -fF -o /tmp/login.log -p $LOGIN_PROCESS_PID`